# Error in Google Map V2

Tags: android, google-maps

I follow the tutorial in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start, and I find there's no correct answer for me.

This is my mainactivity.java with my MainActivity extends FragmentActivity:

```
package com.example.googlemaptest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

And the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

manifest is as below：

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.googlemaptest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.googlemaptest.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-feature   android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"   android:required="true"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission     android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data 
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" 
        />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyB_wRz081KuDphomkrGUNaweTVB843Tt2s" 
        />

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.googlemaptest.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Below are the errors:

```
12-07 19:47:12.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9568): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-07 19:47:12.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9568): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start     activity ComponentInfo{com.example.googlemaptest/com.example.googlemaptest.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
12-07 19:47:12.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9568):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1849)
12-07 19:47:12.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9568):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1870)
12-07 19:47:12.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9568):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
12-07 19:47:12.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9568):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1051)
12-07 19:47:12.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9568):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-07 19:47:12.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9568):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
12-07 19:47:12.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9568):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4319)
12-07 19:47:12.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9568):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-07 19:47:12.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9568):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-07 19:47:12.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9568):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
12-07 19:47:12.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9568):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
12-07 19:47:12.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9568):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-07 19:47:12.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9568): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
12-07 19:47:12.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9568):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
12-07 19:47:12.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9568):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
12-07 19:47:12.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9568):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
12-07 19:47:12.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9568):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
12-07 19:47:12.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9568):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:250)
12-07 19:47:12.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9568):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1742)
12-07 19:47:12.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9568):     at com.example.googlemaptest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:10)
12-07 19:47:12.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9568):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
12-07 19:47:12.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9568):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1813)
12-07 19:47:12.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9568):     ... 11 more
12-07 19:47:12.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9568): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.googlemaptest-2.apk]
12-07 19:47:12.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9568):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
12-07 19:47:12.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9568):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
12-07 19:47:12.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9568):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
12-07 19:47:12.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9568):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
12-07 19:47:12.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9568):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
12-07 19:47:12.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9568):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
12-07 19:47:12.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9568):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
12-07 19:47:12.452: E/AndroidRuntime(9568):     ... 19 more
```

Comment: use this to learn google maps: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

Answer (score 0):

Use supportMapFragment instead of MapFragment.

```
  <fragment  
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
  />

GoogleMap gm;
//oncreate 
setContentView(R.layout.maps)
gm = ((SupportMapFragment)(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))).getMap();
gm.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
gm.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But, I still have a question:What is the use of gm? There is an error in getSupportFragmentManager() with error "Return type for the method is missing"

Comment: @user3077443 actually it's Googlemap class.Now i edited answer.hope u will get it.

Comment: New error:Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.googlemaptest/com.example.googlemaptest.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDdfdfd" /> //map api key

Comment: change like what I mentioned in manifest.add your map api key in value @user3077443 no need of using this.    <meta-data 
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" 
        />